# How to create a mysql column (seconds) calculated from an other column (timestamp)?

Tags: mysql

I need to create a column of seconds calculated from an already existing column of timestamp called 'time'. I tried with a query with  unix_timestamp but it doesn't accept a thing like:

```
UPDATE tempLog SET seconds= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('time')
```

I'm a beginner in stackoverflow and mysql, thanks.

Comment: Don't put `time` in quotes, just `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)`.

Comment: thks Barmar, it worked with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time). But I finally chose to do it with php strtotime because the above method weirdly changed the hour, min and sec of the column timestamp. But it is solved.

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is based on GMT, not local time. So it could change the hour, but shouldn't change minutes and seconds (unless you're in one of the partial-hour timezones).